# I'm on a windows computer but I'm coding with mcpi and I was wondering how I'd put custom commands

Tags: python-3, minecraft

I'm on a windows computer but I'm coding with mcpi and I was wondering how I'd put custom commands. I cannot find any tutorials and no forums are talking about it. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: how does the question relate to the raspberry pi? ... it appears to be a python question

Comment: Because it is python and minecraft and Minecraft Pi

Comment: Minecraft Pi is exclusive to to the Pi, yet you are saying you are on a Windows computer. Are you using VNC to remotely access your Pi? (That opens up another can of worms IMO, so coding directly on the Pi will be the easiest) And there are plenty or resources online to use Minecraft Pi, ex [here](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-minecraft-pi/1).

Comment: What is `mcpi`? Does it emulate a Raspberry Pi on MS Window$?